# why click event only only work on one element?

Tags: javascript

I try to pop up every items and make background go dark, pop up always work, but dark background only work in last element, I already try it whole night, how do I fix it and it will work?

```
const pro_po = function (){
    const item_4_1_1 = document.getElementById('item-4-1-1')
    const item_4_1_2 = document.getElementById('item-4-1-2')
    const item_4_2_1 = document.getElementById('item-4-2-1')
    const item_4_2_2 = document.getElementById('item-4-2-2')
    const item_4_2_3 = document.getElementById('item-4-2-3')
    const ov_bg = document.getElementById('ov-bg')
    const ov_bg_display = document.querySelector('.ov-bg-display')
    document.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
      if(e.target == item_4_1_1 || e.target == item_4_1_2 ){
        item_4_1.style =`display:block`;
        ov_bg.classList.remove('ov-bg-display');
      }else{
        item_4_1.style =`display:none`;
        ov_bg.classList.add('ov-bg-display');
      }
      if(e.target == item_4_2_1 || e.target == item_4_2_2 || e.target == 
      item_4_2_3 ){
        item_4_2.style =`display:block`;
        ov_bg.classList.remove('ov-bg-display');
      }else{
        item_4_2.style =`display:none`;
        ov_bg.classList.add('ov-bg-display');
      }  
    })
}()
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML as well?

Comment: Tip: you can clean up your code by doing `if (e.target.id === 'item-4-1-1')` instead. Or even better, store the id in a variable first like `const id = e.target.id` and use that in the if statements like `if (id === 'item-4-1-1')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 if statements that both change the `ov_bg.classlist`. So after the first if part, the second changes it again. You cant have that part in two separate statements, only in one.

```js
// Adds or removes on ov_bg
if(e.target == item_4_1_1 || e.target == item_4_1_2 ){
    item_4_1.style =`display:block`;
    ov_bg.classList.remove('ov-bg-display');
}else{
    item_4_1.style =`display:none`;
    ov_bg.classList.add('ov-bg-display');
}


if(e.target == item_4_2_1 || e.target == item_4_2_2 || e.target == item_4_2_3 ){
    item_4_2.style =`display:block`;
    ov_bg.classList.remove('ov-bg-display');
}else{
    item_4_2.style =`display:none`;
    ov_bg.classList.add('ov-bg-display'); // Because this else, it will overwrite the previous part
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the issue:

`item_4_2`.style = 'display:block';

and this:

`item_4_2`.style = 'display:none';